# Object metadata deployment through workbench

Tags: deployment, migration-tool

While deploying object metadata of an org's backup using workbench to a new sandbox it is giving errors
like "Cannot create a new component with the namespace: pse. Only components in the same namespace as the organization can be created through the API". Please guide me how can i deploy it successfully.

Comment: Would be interested to see your package.xml file

Answer (score 1):

`pse` is the namespace for managed package "Professional Services Automation" by FinancialForce. You would need to install that package in the Sandbox prior to trying to deploy any components referencing that namespace (as a side note, there are only a few metadata types that you can actually update in a managed package, are you sure you have the correct package.xml?)